# Parse Push Notifications When Specific Users Make Post

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I recently updated an app to be configured with back-end server at Parse.  They login using either username, twitter credentials, or Facebook credentials.  From there, they can make some 'posts', which just add a row to an object I have set up in the Parse dashboard.

I know that Parse has some push notification capabilities, but I was wondering about one specific use.  Is there a way for a user to 'follow' another user, and receive a `Push Notification` every time that user posts something?  If so, is that something that can be handled via Native Parse and iOS functions, or must `Cloud-Code` be set up for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using client-side push (which you would have to enable in your app settings on Parse in case it is disabled).

You can then use this code to send pushes from the device of the user creating the post to all of his followers:

```
// Send a notification to all devices subscribed to the "Giants" channel.
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setChannel:/* Set the channels here */];
[push setMessage:@"User XYZ just posted something"];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending/iOS

Comment: Thanks.  I looked at the AnyPic tutorial to see about how to 'Follow' other people on there, but with some issues.  I couldn't get the example app to run on my computer, and they only demonstrated how to show Facebook friends.  This is an issue as my app lets you use username, Facebook, OR Twitter to log in, so not quite complete.  Is there a good tutorial anywhere for Parse on following a user easily?

Comment: Or does this summarize it fairly well?

Perform action when person does something like click on a profile picture.  Action will add that profile's username to the channels column of their PFInstallation.  Then, when someone makes a new post, send the code to send a push notification to all installations that have that specific username in their channel column?

Comment: That's something I would have suggested, yes. Subscribe people to a channel that matches the username for example and send out a push to that channel each time the user posts something

Comment: Only thing I would add to this is that it may be better to use the objectId of the user to subscribe too. I imagine the user may have the option to edit their username? and therefore could change, where as the objectId will always stay constant

Comment: I am trying @JayDev to get this all set up, but running into an issue.  I cannot retrieve the objectId key at all.  I have `PFUser *me = [PFUser currentUser];` and then try using `NSString *test = me[@"objectId"];` but it keeps returning null.  What is going on?